# how do i do edit the frequency of backups in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, backup

i already have existing maintenance plans and i would like to edit the frequency at which they occur. is this possible to do?

Comment: not programming-related in any way - belongs on Serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can either modify the properties of the maintanance plan or you can modify the properties of the job that comprises the maintenence plan.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server Management Studio open up the maintenance plan folder in the left pane. Choose the maintenance plan you want to modify by right-clicking and choosing modify. There should be a calendar button that you can click on for each subplan where you can set the frequency and time the job will run.